# Strange error during create session in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I started to receive next error when I create a session with **/workbook/createSession** in Microsoft Graph API for excel workbook.

```
{
    code: 'forbiddenUncategorized',
    message: 'The request is not allowed.',
    innerError: {
      code: 'SessionMemoryQuotaExceededOnOpenWorkbook',
      message: "We're sorry, but we can't open this workbook."
    },
    date: '2023-05-16T12:28:54',
    'request-id': 'fa416196-93db-4803-844c-b36e95c31145',
    'client-request-id': 'fa416196-93db-4803-844c-b36e95c31145'
  }
```

I get such mistake for only one document from many.
Maybe someone knows what could be the reason for this error?

Comment: What's the size of the file?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know because this client's file. But I know that in case of the large file I get other error about the file exceeds XX mB and cannot be opened.